# For what values of $b$ (if any), does $ \sqrt{b^2 + b - \sqrt{b^2+b-\sqrt{b^2 + b - \cdots}}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For what values of $b$, does
$$ \sqrt{b^2 + b - \sqrt{b^2+b-\sqrt{b^2 + b - \cdots}}}$$

converge?

Comment: Surely it converges for $b=0$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: Suppose it converges to $a$, then $a = (-1 \pm \sqrt{4 + 4(b^2 + b)})/2$ and we then want $4 + 4(b^2 + b) \ge 0$ which reduces to $b^2 + b + 1 \ge 0$ which is true for all $b$.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "does it converge", that implies a sequence.
Exactly what sequence does this infinite nested radical represent?  I'll suppose it's the sequence $0, \sqrt{b^2+b}, \sqrt{b^2+b - \sqrt{b^2+b}}, \ldots$, i.e. $0, f(0), f(f(0)), \ldots$, where
$f(x) = \sqrt{b^2 + b - x}$.  Also, I'll assume you're dealing with real numbers here.

If it converges at all, the limit $L$ should be a stable fixed point
of the function $f$.

The fixed point is $b$ if $b \ge 0$, $-b-1$ if $b \le -1$, and there is no real fixed point if $-1 < b < 0$.  Since $b$ and $-1-b$ produce the same $b^2+b$, I'll just look at the case $b \ge 0$.  Stability depends on the absolute value of the derivative at the fixed point: in this case

$$ |f'(b)| = \dfrac{1}{2b} \le 1 \ \text{iff}\ b \ge \dfrac{1}{2} $$

So we certainly need $b \ge 1/2$ for convergence to $b$, while the
case $b=1/2$ is doubtful.  In this case, for $b=1/2$ we have
$f(f(x)) > x$ for $1/2 < x < 3/4$, so $b = 1/2$ is unstable.

Once we have stability, the next question is whether the initial point $0$ is in the basin of attraction of the fixed point.

Tt turns out that between $0$ and $b$ there is a $2$-cycle

$$ \eqalign{f\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{4b^2 + 4b - 3}}{2}\right) &=\frac{1+\sqrt{4b^2 + 4b - 3}}{2}\cr  f\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{4b^2 + 4b - 3}}{2}\right) &=\frac{1-\sqrt{4b^2 + 4b - 3}}{2} \cr}$$

for $1/2 < b \le (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$, so that we only have convergence
if $b > (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$.  For $b > (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$ the function $f$ maps the interval $[0, b^2+b]$ into itself, with no $2$-cycle and only one fixed point, so we do get convergence.